# How to convert autopytoexe folder into a single executable?

Tags: python

I used autopytoexe to convert a my .py into a .exe. I use the folder mode because i need some sounds and png that are stored in a folder within the .py. Afterall i succeded to have a folder containing my sounds, png and main.exe that make my app run. Now i want to convert this exe into an apk to use it on my phone. My problem is how to convert a folder containing a.exe into a single executable. It is even possible ?

Best regards,

OP

autpytoexe --> folder containing main.exe --> one .exe that make main.exe run with the sounds and .png

Comment: Converting a folder containing an executable into a single executable is not directly possible. However, you can package your Python application along with its dependencies into a single executable using tools like `PyInstaller` or `cx_Freeze`.